# python celery working on diffrent machine

Tags: python, celery

I have website where user will be able to download celery and run the task,
Now i will have thousand of them to download celery and run my task how do i identify which celery is running and if i want to send any command to celery how do i send it to particular celery. is there a way i can name them and identify

```
import platform
import socket
os=platform.system()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
hostname = (socket.gethostname())
```

i will get this info if run the code and post the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what are you looking for, if you need to identify machine you are working on you can use as you written:

```
import socket
socket.gethostname()
```

You can change this name on the system using

```
sudo hostname newname
```

But I am not sure if this is what are you looking for.

Comment: i will have thousand of celery working on different mach, how will i send request to particular celery